# jquery mobile table reflow mode, heading text color issue

Tags: jquery, mobile

I created a table with reflow mode in jquery mobile.  I need to color the heading text.  The heading text color works fine when not in reflow mode.  When in reflow mode, the heading text color reverts to default color.

Here is the code:

```
$("#mytable").append(
'<thead>' +
'<tr>' +
'<th style="color:#2554C7">Taxing Entity</th>' +
'<th style="color:#2554C7">Tax Rate</th>' +
'<th style="color:#2554C7">Homestead Exemption</th>' +
'</tr>' +
'</thead>' +
'<tbody>' +
'<tr>' +
'<th>City of Allen</th>' +
'<td>0.5530</td>' +
'<td>N</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
'<th>City of Arlington</th>' +
'<td>0.6480</td>' +
'<td>Y</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'<tr>' +
'</tbody>'
);

$("#mytable").table( "refresh" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
style="color:#2554C7!important"
```

Comment: Could you check you DOM and see if the style you apply is there?